# Refactoring SCSS comma selector

Tags: css, sass

I'm refactoring some existing CSS to use SCSS. I have the following in the original CSS:

```
.section .recipient_group_toggle i.fa-plus,
.section.toggled .recipient_group_toggle i.fa-minus {
    display:inline-block;    
}
.section .recipient_group_toggle i.fa-minus,
.section.toggled .recipient_group_toggle i.fa-plus {
    display:none;
}
```

I've got:

```
.section {
    .recipient_group_toggle {
        i.fa-plus {
            display:inline-block;   
        }
        i.fa-minus {
            display:none;   
        }
    }

    &.toggled {
        .recipient_group_toggle {
            i.fa-plus {
                display:none;
            }
            i.fa-minus {
                display:inline-block;   
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Which isn't ideal, as it has four separate definitions. Is there a better way of doing this that's 'SCSS-ey' but which lets me define the different display values only once?

Comment: I'll be honest, the first thing looks... more streamlined in general. Unless there is a reason to make this "more sassy" (which there shouldn't be), this is a part you should skip. Your sass looks like it made it more complex.

Comment: Also note that the original CSS syntax is 100% valid SCSS, in case you weren't clear on that. There's no reason to nest things in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [will do it](https://sass-lang.com/playground/#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), only writes `display` values once, and it's pretty `sass`-y:

```scss
$items: 
  "plus" "minus" inline-block,
  "minus" "plus" none;
$path: ".recipient_group_toggle i.fa-";

@each $a, $b, $val in $items {
  .section {
    #{$path}#{$a},
    &.toggled #{$path}#{$b} {
      display: $val;
    }
  }
}
```

I would [write it as a @mixin](https://sass-lang.com/playground/#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), so I could re-use it with different values or even in other projects.

Keep in mind:

- sacrificing code readability for brevity is almost never a good thing <sup>***1***</sup>.
- CSS is valid SCSS. Always.

Which means: although the snippet above produces the desired outcome, there's a strong case to be made about keeping the initial CSS form, because it is significantly easier to understand for the vast pool of developers who are comfortable reading CSS but are not familiar with less popular SCSS syntax and techniques.

---

***<sup>1</sup>*** - Not convinced? Imagine having someone in your team writing [code like this](https://sass-lang.com/playground/#MTElMjRpJTNBJTIycGwlMjIlMjJtaW4lMjJpbmxpbmUtYmxvY2slMkMlMjJtaW4lMjIlMjJwbCUyMm5vbmUlM0IlMjRwJTNBJTIyLnJlY2lwaWVudF9ncm91cF90b2dnbGUlMjBpLmZhLSUyMiUzQiUwQSU0MGVhY2glMjAlMjRhJTJDJTI0YiUyQyUyNHYlMjBpbiUyMCUyNGklN0Iuc2VjdGlvbiU3QiUyMyU3QiUyNHAlN0QlMjMlN0IlMjRhJTdEdXMlMkMlMjYudG9nZ2xlZCUyMCUyMyU3QiUyNHAlN0QlMjMlN0IlMjRiJTdEdXMlN0JkaXNwbGF5JTNBJTI0diU3RCU3RCU3RA==), and then you having to modify it, to cover some edge case.